# Writing a sql query to find the doctor whose patients have the most different type of diseases

Tags: sql

I am trying to figure out how to write this query and I am having a really hard time.

Here are the tables relevant to the question:

**Doctors** table with columns:

```
D_ID, D_NAME, D_GENDER, D_AGE, D_SPECIALIZATION, D_YEARS_OF_EXPERIENCE, D_CONTACT, D_STREET, D_CITY
```

**Patients** table:

```
P_ID, P_NAME, P_GENDER, P_AGE, P_DISEASE, P_CONTACT, P_STREET, P_CITY
```

**P_Assignment** table :

```
P_ID, D_ID
```

and the question is:

Find the doctor whose patients have the most different type of diseases.
(Your result should display the doctor's name.)

Thanks for everyone who helped out with this, unfortunately I wasn't able to use any of the answers provided here as it include things we have not learned about in this class. I ended up finding a solution through the help of a friend. This is what we came up with:

```
SELECT d_name
FROM Doctors
WHERE d_id IN (
  SELECT d_id
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT d_id, p_disease
    FROM P_Assignment, Patients
    WHERE P_Assignment.p_id = Patients.p_id
  ) AS p1
  GROUP BY d_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= ALL (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT d_id, p_disease
      FROM P_Assignment, Patients
      WHERE P_Assignment.p_id = Patients.p_id
    ) AS p2
    GROUP BY d_id
  )
);
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Make it easy to assist you; [mcve].

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

We can try an aggregation query with the help of the `RANK` analytic function:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT d.D_ID, d.D_NAME, COUNT(DISTINCT p.P_DISEASE) AS disease_cnt,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT p.P_DISEASE) DESC) rnk
    FROM P_ASSIGNMENT pa
    INNER JOIN DOCTORS d ON pa.D_ID = d.D_ID
    INNER JOIN PATIENTS p ON p.P_ID = pa.P_ID
    GROUP BY d.D_ID, d.D_NAME
)

SELECT D_ID, D_NAME, disease_cnt
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use GROUP BY and DISTINCT COUNT to get the doctor with maximum distinct diseases. I assume it is SQL Server.

```sql
;WITH CTE_DiseasesCount AS
(
SELECT D_ID, D_NAME,COUNT(DISTINCT P_DISEASE) AS CountOfDistinctDiseases
FROM PATIENTS AS p
INNER JOIN P_ASSIGNMENT as a
ON a.P_ID = p.P_ID
INNER JOIN DOCTORS as d
ON d.D_ID = a.d_ID
GROUP BY D_ID,D_NAME
)
SELECT TOP 1 D_NAME FROM CTE_DiseasesCount
ORDER BY CountOfDistinctDiseases DESC;
```

Comment: @jarlh, I have updated my answer. I should have mentioned it. sorry.